# myEditText.setText not refreshing on page

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a simple activity which needs to accept a 4-digit PIN number using a custom pin-pad (buttons on the screen). The digits are stored in four EditTexts.

When I click a button, the text in the button is stored in a `char[]` (`myEditText.getText()` shows that this is happening), the focus is moved to the next `EditText` through an `onFocusListener()` and the `Log` output shows that this is all happening correctly.

```
11-20 10:19:56.969: I/DebugA(17742): Pin1 updated to: 1 // Pin1 is the ID
11-20 10:19:58.289: I/DebugA(17742): Pin2 updated to: 2 // '2' is Pin2.getText()
11-20 10:19:58.849: I/DebugA(17742): Pin3 updated to: 3
11-20 10:19:59.659: I/DebugA(17742): Pin4 updated to: 4
```

The screen itself is simply not being updated. The EditTexts all appear empty, even though the code executes perfectly.

I have looked through a whole heap of answers on SO and tried many of the suggestions with absolutely no luck, so I am posting this question which I hope someone can shed some light on! Has anyone else had this happen?

Here's some of the layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/layout1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginTop="42dp" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/Pin1"
    android:tag="Pin1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="2"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/Pin2"
    android:maxLength="1"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />

...
...
...

</RelativeLayout>
```

...and the buttons are:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/layout2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
android:layout_below="@+id/layout1" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="btnPinClick"
    android:text="1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button02"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="btnPinClick"
    android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
    android:text="2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button03"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="btnPinClick"
    android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
    android:text="3" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The activity is a standard activity (`MyActivity extends Activity`).

Any thoughts?

**UPDATE**
Here's some of the java as requested:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_login, null);

    EditText Pin1 = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.Pin1);
    Pin1.setOnFocusChangeListener(focusListener);
    Pin1.setText("1");                 // <--THIS HAS NO EFFECT
    EditText Pin2 = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.Pin2);
    Pin2.setOnFocusChangeListener(focusListener);
    EditText Pin3 = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.Pin3);
    Pin3.setOnFocusChangeListener(focusListener);
    EditText Pin4 = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.Pin4);
    Pin4.setOnFocusChangeListener(focusListener);
...
...
...
}
```

The `Onclick` method is:

```
public void btnPinClick(View btnPin) {
    String PinNumber = ((Button)btnPin).getText().toString();
    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_login, null);

    ArrayList<View> views = (ArrayList<View>) layout.getFocusables(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
    EditText nextItem = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < views.size(); i++) {
                    // THIS IS THE CORRECT EditText FOR EACH OF THESE
        EditText textBox = (EditText) views.get(i);
        if (textBox.getTag().toString().equals(currentText)) {
            textBox.setText(PinNumber);
            pin[i] = PinNumber.toCharArray()[0];
            Log.i("DebugA", textBox.getTag().toString() + " updated to: " + textBox.getText().toString());
            textBox.invalidate();
            textBox.refreshDrawableState();
            if(i+1 < views.size()) {
                nextItem = (EditText) views.get(i+1);
            }
            else {
                doCheckPin();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    if(nextItem != null){
        nextItem.requestFocus();
        currentText = nextItem.getTag().toString();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**
Here is the code for the OnFocusChangeListener as requested:

```
protected OnFocusChangeListener focusListener = new OnFocusChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(hasFocus) {
                            //THIS SIMPLY SETS A VARIABLE STRING TO SAY WHICH 
                            //EditText HAS FOCUS.
            currentText = v.getTag().toString();
        }

    }
};
```

Comment: I should also add that calling `Pin1.setText()` on my `OnCreate` ovveride has no effect.

Comment: Post the relevant Java code so we can see what is happening. Are you accidentally covering the EditText with another?

Comment: Thanks @Sam, question updated. Both the `onclick` and the `OnCreate` seem to be pulling in the correct elements from the layout...

Comment: Please post the code for focusListener.

Comment: why are you inflating a layout in your standard activity? especially after using `setContentView()` on the same layout? try removing the inflation and its dependencies. you might be affecting edittexts in the wrong view hierarchies. A parallel dimension, if you will.

Comment: @mango, you are absolutely correct! What a simple error. Clearly this was a case of not referencing the correct elements as alluded to by @Sam! I have removed all instances of the layout inflater and it is now working. I must be tired. I have wasted a LOT of time on this. Could you please post your comment as an answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using a layout inflater in addition to setContentView in your activity. And affecting the edittexts referenced by the inflater. Try removing use of the inflater and rely solely on setContentView for this part of the activity. You might be performing in an incorrect view hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks Mango. I had been working with Fragments for the last week or so and then switched to a straight up activity. Really just needed a fresh set of eyes on this one!